# How return `$resource` promise response?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I require the user details for multiple areas. I tried to return the details using a generic function. But i am getting the result as `undefined`. i understand that, I require to use the `$differed` to get the reuslt. But I don't have any idea about my current scenario.

anyone help me here please?

here is my function:

```
$scope.currentUserInfo = function () {

        var userDetails;

        server.getProfile.get().$promise.then(function ( response ) {

            if( response.Message.toUpperCase().indexOf('SUCCESS') != -1) {

                return  userDetails = response;

            }

            return "Not able to get the user details this time"

        })

        return userDetails;

    }

$scope.currentUser =  $scope.currentUserInfo();
console.log( $scope.currentUser ) //undefined.



var function1 = function () {

    $scope.currentUserInfo(); //once user details available do further

     $scope.age = $scope.currentUser.age;

}

var function2 = function () {

    $scope.currentUserInfo(); //once user details available do further

    $scope.name = $scope.currentUser.name;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

server.getProfile.get() is an asynchronous call. 
The `return userDetails;` line in `$scope.currentUserInfo` function will get executed even if the `server.getProfile.get()` call is not yet finish. 
Try this:

```
$scope.currentUserInfo = function () {

    server.getProfile.get().$promise.then(function ( response ) {

        if( response.Message.toUpperCase().indexOf('SUCCESS') != -1) {

            $scope.currentUser = response;

        }

        $scope.message =  "Not able to get the user details this time";


    })

}
```

`$scope.currentUser` will be populated after the ajax call is finish. I assume that you are using `$scope.currentUser` in your html bindings so when the value changes it will automatically reflect in your view

Comment: I agree. But Up to I receive the value from the `$scope.currentUser` I would like to `pause` other functions - how to do?

Comment: What do you mean by pause other functions?

Comment: how or where do you use `function1` and `function2`?  if for instance you want to do something when `$scope.currentUser` changes, you may want to `watch` `$scope.currentUser`